# Give the exact values of the mean time plots (seqmtplot)

Tags: r, plot, sequence, traminer

I would like to extract the exact values of my mean time plots for each different state that I defined to further analyse my clusters. The mean time plots don't allow me to easily read those 
values. Is there a way to extract those values?

Here you have an example script using the mvad dataset available in TraMineR, available in R.

```
library(TraMineR) 
data(mvad)
mvad.alphabet <- c("employment", "FE", "HE", "joblessness", "school",
                      "training")
mvad.labels <- c("Employment", "Further Education", "Higher Education",
                    "Joblessness", "School", "Training")
mvad.scodes <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")

## Define sequence objects
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], alphabet = mvad.alphabet,
                     states = mvad.scodes, labels = mvad.labels, weights = mvad$weight, xtstep = 6)
## seqmtPlot
seqmtplot(mvad.seq, group=mvad$gcse5eq, withlegend=TRUE, border=NA, xtstep=3, sortv="from.start") #Example of seqmtplot. How can I extract the mean time values from these plots?
```

Thanks in advance,
Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This values can be obtained using the `seqmeant` function.

```
seqmeant(mvad.seq)
```

However, this function doesn't have a `group` argument. You need to compute this information separately for each group. For the "no" group, you can use

```
seqmeant(mvad.seq[mvad$gcse5eq=="no", ])
```

If you want to compute it for each group, you can use the `by` function:

```
by(mvad.seq, mvad$gcse5eq, seqmeant)
```

Hope this helps!

PS: Some of the argument you used for `seqmtplot` are not meaningful in this case, you should use

```
seqmtplot(mvad.seq, group=mvad$gcse5eq, withlegend=TRUE)
```